# What is the "Options property"?

Tags: asp.net

This is a practice problem for Microsoft Certificate Exam 70-515(ASP.NET 4) from Measure Up.
I am not sure the meaning of "Options property" here.
I know the answer but my question is what is "Options property"?

You are using the .NET Framework 4 and Visual Studio 2010 to create a server control.
When the server control is added to a Web Form from the Visual Studio toolbox, you want to ensure that the following markup is added to the page:

```
<uc:MyControl ID="MyControl1" runat="server" BackColor="beige" ForeColor="black" />
```

You also want to ensure that when the control is selected on the Web Form, the Options property is displayed.
What should you do?

1. Decorate the class with the ToolboxData attribute and the Options property with the DefaultProperty attribute.
2. Decorate the class with the ToolboxItem attribute and the DefaultProperty attribute.
3. Decorate the class with the ToolboxItem attribute and the Options property with the DefaultProperty attribute.
4. Decorate the class with the ToolboxData attribute and the DefaultProperty attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A property called "Options" which is (all of the below):

1. User-defined.
2. Modifiable in the "Properties Window" in the Visual Studio 2010 Designer.
3. Accessible in the ASPX markup.
4. Defined in the code-behind class for the UserControl.
5. Accessible in the code-behind class for the UserControl.